# Error importing nebula.gl into custom PyDeck deck.gl layer

Tags: python, interactive, ipywidgets, deck.gl, pydeck

I'm trying to import nebula.gl in order to make a selection layer for PyDeck (working on reproducint this [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/deckgl-and-nebulagl-editablegeojsonlayer-no-react-forked-l0n65?file=/app.js:387-388)). However, I'm getting an error in the console

[image]

when I try to [import nebula](https://github.com/cornhundred/nebula_select_layer/blob/master/labeled-geojson-layer.js#L5)

```
import { EditableGeoJsonLayer, DrawPolygonMode } from 'nebula.gl';
```

However, yarn and webpack appear to build correctly. The repo and place where nebula.gl is imported is [here](https://github.com/cornhundred/nebula_select_layer/blob/master/labeled-geojson-layer.js#L5)

Comment: Do you have a typescript package installed in your package.json?